# Appending a list to another list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a `.txt` file that contains data like this :

```
math,mathematics
data,machine-learning-model
machine-learning,statistics,unsupervised-learning,books
orange,lda
machine-learning,deep-learning,keras,tensorflow
keras,similarity,distance,features
```

Now, I want to store each line as a list in a bigger list .

The expected output for sentences is something  like this :

```
sentences = [['math', 'mathematics'],
['data', 'machine-learning-model'],
['machine-learning', 'statistics', 'unsupervised-learning', 'books'],
['orange', 'lda']]
```

This is what I tried :

```
temp_tokens = []
sentences = []

fp  = open('tags.txt')
lines = fp.readlines()
for line in lines:
    temp_tokens.clear()
    for word in line.split(','):
        if word.strip('\n'):
            temp_tokens.append(word)
            temp_tokens = [e.replace('\n','') for e in temp_tokens]
    
    print(temp_tokens)
    sentences.append(temp_tokens)
    

print(sentences)
```

Now , when I `print(temp_tokens)` , I get the following output :

```
['math', 'mathematics']
['data', 'machine-learning-model']
['machine-learning', 'statistics', 'unsupervised-learning', 'books']
['orange', 'lda']
['machine-learning', 'deep-learning', 'keras', 'tensorflow']
['keras', 'similarity', 'distance', 'features']
['machine-learning']
```

which is perfectly fine. But, the individual lists are not properly appended to the list `sentences`. When I do `sentences.append(temp_tokens)`. The sentences list looks like this :

It only contains the individual tokens in each line and not the row itself as a list .

```
[['data'], ['machine-learning'], ['orange'], ['machine-learning'], ['keras'], ['machine-learning\n'], ['machine-learning'], ['dataset'], ['lstm\n'], ['python'], ['python'], ['reinforcement-learning'], ['machine-learning'], ['machine-learning'], ['machine-learning'], ['machine-learning'], ['overfitting'], ['machine-learning'], ['machine-learning'], ['time-series'], ['machine-learning'], ['linear-regression'], ['python'], ['keras'], ['python'], ['python'], ['pytorch\n'], ['machine-learning'], ['machine-learning'], ['machine-learning'], ['machine-learning'], ['gradient-descent\n'], ['python'], ['image'], ['dataset'], ['python'], ['neural-network'], ['machine-learning'], ['feature-selection'], ['nlp'], ['machine-learning'], ['python'], ['machine-learning'], ['cnn'], ['machine-learning'], ['neural-network'], ['machine-learning'], ['machine-learning'], ['deep-learning'], ['machine-learning'], ['python'], ['tensorflow'], ['machine-learning'], ['machine-learning'], ['machine-learning']
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my code ? Why is the list '`temp_tokens`' not appended to '`sentences`' as a complete list but only as individual tokens ?

Can someone explain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
sentences = []
fp  = open('tags.txt')
for line in fp.readlines():
    temp_tokens = line.strip().split(",")
    sentences.append(temp_tokens)
print(sentences)
```

or more cleanly:

```
sentences = []
with open('tags.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp.readlines():
        sentences.append(line.strip().split(","))
print(sentences)
```

Comment: It worked ! Thanks a lot . But , can you tell me what was wrong with my original code ? I can't find any mistake there

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Lists are mutable. Like as create a list, it will be created in an address and when it is used somewhere else, the address is passed there, not the items in it. so every time you append temp_tokens in sentences, it passes the address of it not the items. so when you change temp_tokens again it changes what is there in that address. But the address was also passed to the sentences. So it ultimately go to that address and change it. So while printing, sentences list go to that address and prints what was there after changes not that was there earlier.

Comment: You could use:
sentences.append(temp_tokens[:])
this will copy the items of temp_tokens in another address not the address that it was on earlier

Answer (score 2):

Alternativey, use

```
with open('tags.txt') as fp:
    sentences = [line.strip().split(',') for line in fp]
print(sentences)
```